# Sharing image with UIActivityViewController is blank/corrupt in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

It appears I'm only having this bug in iOS 8. I'm trying to share an image and a bit of text with `UIActivityViewController` to myself for testing. Sometimes, the shared image results in a question mark on what was supposed to be a shared image, and tapping on it doesn't do anything in the iMessage thread because it's either blank or corrupt. If I go back to my app and try to share again, sometimes the image does get shared perfectly and isn't blank.

Code I'm using (works perfectly in iOS 7):

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sent from http://appstore.com/appname"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeImage"]]applicationActivities:nil];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypeAirDrop];

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I'm trying to figure out why this is happening sometimes, and how to fix it. I'd appreciate any help. Attached a screenshot of issue/bug:

[image]

Comment: At another place of the app [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeImage"] works?

Comment: Works great when it wants to. And 100% in iOS 7. Makes me think it's an Apple bug with their remote view controllers. Sharing via Email through `UIActivityViewController`also times out sometimes since iOS 8.

Comment: Did you every find a solution to this? We are seeing the same intermittent corrupted images, except we are using mail sharing.

Comment: @CargoMeister I did not find a solution, which stinks. This issue only started on iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround for video file sharing. May be you can try the same for images.

I had video data that I first saved to a file in documents directory and then I attached that file.

```
//write to a file 
 [videoData writeToFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image.mov"] atomically:YES];

(IBAction)ShareVideoWihFacebook:(id)sender {
//get the file url NSString* path =[NSHomeDirectory()stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image.mov"];

NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

UIActivityViewController * activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[videoURL,@"Created by ..."] applicationActivities:NULL];


[activityVC setExcludedActivityTypes:@[ UIActivityTypeMail,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypePrint,        UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypeMessage,UIActivityTypeAirDrop,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll]];

[activityVC setValue:@"My Video" forKey:@"subject"];

[activityVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
//NSLog(@"completed dialog - activity: %@ - finished flag: %d", activityType, completed);
}];

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old threat, but I recently got into the same kind of situation.
First of all, save the file you wanna share, to a temp. directory, and then you wanna share the url, by using `url.absoluteUrl`. Doing the absoluteUrl seems very important.